# How to do Operator overloading with move semantics in c++? (Elegantly)

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, move-semantics, generic-programming

```cpp
class T {
    size_t *pData;          // Memory allocated in the constructor
    friend T operator+(const T& a, const T& b);
};
T operator+(const T& a, const T& b){        // Op 1
        T c;                            // malloc()
        *c.pData = *a.pData + *b.pData;
        return c;
}

T do_something(){
    /* Implementation details */
    return T_Obj;
}
```

A simple `class T` with dynamic memory. Consider

```
T a,b,c;
c = a + b;                                      // Case 1
c = a + do_something(b);            // Case 2
c = do_something(a) + b;            // Case 3
c = do_something(a) + do_something(b);           // Case 4
```

- Case 1 uses 1 malloc()
- Case 2 uses 2 malloc()
- Case 3 uses 2 malloc()
- Case 4 uses 3 malloc()

We can do better by addiitonally defining,

```
T& operator+(const T& a, T&& b){           // Op 2
                    // no malloc() steeling data from b rvalue
        *b.pData = *a.pData + *b.pData;
        return b;
}
```

Case 2 now only uses 1 malloc(), but what about Case 3? do we need to define Op 3?

```
T& operator+(T&& a, const T& b){            // Op 3
                    // no malloc() steeling data from a rvalue
        *b.pData = *a.pData + *b.pData;
        return b;
}
```

Further, if we do define Op 2 and Op 3, given the fact that an rvalue reference can bind to an lvalue reference, the compiler now has two equally plausible function definitions to call in Case 4

```
T& operator+(const T& a, T&& b);        // Op 2 rvalue binding to a
T& operator+(T&& a, const T& b);        // Op 3 rvalue binding to b
```

the compiler would complain about an ambiguous function call, would defining Op 4 help work around the compiler's ambiguous function call problem? as we gain no additional performance with Op 4

```
T& operator+(T&& a, T&& b){          // Op 4
                    // no malloc() can steel data from a or b rvalue
        *b.pData = *a.pData + *b.pData;
        return b;
}
```

With Op 1, Op 2, Op 3 and Op 4, we have

- Case 1: 1 malloc (Op 1 is called)
- Case 2: 1 malloc (Op 2 is called)
- Case 3: 1 malloc (Op 3 is called)
- Case 4: 1 malloc (Op 4 is called)

If all my understanding is correct, we will need four function signatures per operator. This somehow doesn't seem right, as it is quite a lot of boilerplate and code duplication per operator. Am I missing something? Is there an elegant way of achieving the same?

Comment: Your `operator+` is a little incoherent with the typical expectation of `+`. Generally `operator+` acts on two binary operands and returns a _new_ object without mutating the two inputs. Modifying the inputs in this case would be undesirable and unexpected by most C++ developers. This inefficiency already occurs with standard types as well, such as `std::string`'s `operator+`

Comment: @Eljay You are right `const T&&` doesn't make sense. I have made the edit

Comment: @Human-Compiler Note that I am only reusing rvalues. Modifying the input, in this case, is not unexpected or undesirable as the rvalue is anyway going to be destroyed soon. Reusing the rvalue can save on a move (or in the worst even a copy). It can quickly become significant based on the size of `T` and the number of times `+` is performed in the loop.

Comment: Most matrix libraries use [lazy operation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html) (which also has its pro/cons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is performant and elegant but makes use of a macro.

---

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

#define OPERATOR_Fn(Op)         \
template<typename T1, typename T2>          \
friend auto operator Op (T1&& a, T2&& b)          \
           -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T1>,std::decay_t<T2>>::value,std::decay_t<T1>>::type \
{                                                           \
    constexpr bool a_or_b = !std::is_reference<T1>::value;            \
    std::decay_t<T1> c((a_or_b? std::forward<T1>(a) : std::forward<T2>(b)));  \
            \
   *c.pData = *c.pData Op (!a_or_b? *a.pData : *b.pData);           \
    return c;                           \
}                   \

struct T {
    T(): pData(new size_t(1)) {std::cout << "malloc" << '\n';}
    ~T() {delete pData;}
    T(const T& b): pData(new size_t(1)) { *pData = *b.pData; std::cout << "malloc" << '\n';}
    T(T&& b){
        pData = b.pData;
        b.pData = nullptr;
        std::cout<< "move constructing" << '\n';
    }

    size_t *pData;          // Memory allocated in the constructor              

    OPERATOR_Fn(+);
    OPERATOR_Fn(-);
    OPERATOR_Fn(&);
    OPERATOR_Fn(|);
};
```

You can simplify the type_traits expression to make the code more readable by defining something like this

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct enable_if_same_on_decay{
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<std::decay_t<T1>, std::decay_t<T2>>::value;
    typedef std::enable_if<value,std::decay_t<T>>::type type;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
using enable_if_same_on_decay_t = typename enable_if_same_on_decay<T1,T2>::type;
```

The complex type_traits expression

```
-> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T1>,std::decay_t<T2>>::value,std::decay_t<T1>>::type
```

simply becomes

```
-> enable_if_same_on_decay_t<T1,T2>
```

Comment: This is `friend`ing _all possible operators_ where the left and right operands are the same (note: this is _not_ constrained to just `T`). Additionally the macro is highly coupled to the actual type it defines it for (since it hard-codes `pData`), so this isn't a particularly scalable solution.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to not try to steal resources with `operator+` (or any binary operators) and design a more appropriate that may reuse the data in some way<sup>1</sup>. This should be your APIs idiomatic way for building, if not the only way (if you want to avoid the issue altogether).

---

Binary operators in C++ like `operator+` have the general expectation/convention that it returns a different object *without mutating any of its inputs*. Defining an `operator+` to operate with Rvalues in addition to Lvalues introduces an unconventional interface that will raise confusion for most C++ developers.

Consider your **case 4** example:

```cpp
c = do_something(a) + do_something(b);           // Case 4
```

Which resource is stolen, `a` or `b`? What if `a` is not big enough to support the result needed from `b` as well (assuming this uses a resizing buffer)? There's no general case that makes this a simple solution.

Additionally, there is no way to distinguish different kinds of Rvalues on an API like Xvalues (the result of `std::move`) from PRvalues (the result of a function that returns a value). This means that your same API could be called:

```cpp
c = std::move(a) + std::move(b);
```

And in such a case, depending on your above heuristic, only one of `a` *or* `b` might have its resource stolen, which is strange. This would result in the lifetime of the underlying resource *not being extended* to `c`, which may go against the developers intuition (consider, for example, if the resource in `a` or `b` has observable side-effects, like logging or other system interactions)

**Note:** It's worth noting that `std::string` in C++ has the same issue, where `operator+` is inefficient. The general recommendation to reuse buffers is to make use of `operator+=` in such a case

---

<sup>1</sup> A better solution to such a problem is to create a proper method of building in some way, and using this consistently. This could be through well-named functions, a proper `builder` class of some kind, or just using the compound operators like `operator+=`

This could even be done through a template helper function that folds a series of arguments into a `+=` concatenation series. Assuming this is in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or above, this can be done easily:

```cpp
template <typename...Args>
auto concat(Args&&...args) -> SomeType
{
    auto result = SomeType{}; // assuming default-constructible

    (result += ... += std::forward<Args>(args));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The developer intent is clear from his use of `std::move(Obj)`. It evident that the developer is no longer interested in the `Obj` object any longer. Ex: 
`vector<int> v1 = {1,2,3}; vector<int> v2; v2 = std::move(v1);` `v1` is put in an default state, waiting to be destroyed. It is the developer's responsibility to not use `v1` again after the move Same is the case in your example
`c = std::move(a) + std::move(b); `  Shows that the developer is no longer interested in both a and b. Hence their heap can savely be reused

Comment: This isn't about intent, it's about asymmetry with typical expectations and about unexpectedly different lifetimes. Object `a` or `b` _might_ have the underlying resource live longer depending on a black-box heuristic of your library. That's not particularly coherent. Just because you _can_ do something in C++ does not mean you _should_ or that the approach is clear to other developers

Comment: Providing a proper interface for this, such as what I have suggested, makes this clear through existing conventions. There's no source of ambiguity, confusion, or anything. Yes, if you want to overload all 4 to do this, you can -- but I don't suspect C++ developers will respond well to such code.

Comment: Your "lifetime" issue already happens with move constructor/assignment which `swap` instead of resetting input. if user is **really** concerned about status of its moved object, he/she has to reset manually after (or see documentation if the status is specified).

Answer (score 0):

technically it's feasible. but probably you should consider a design change.
the code is just a POC.
it has a UB but it works on gcc and clang...

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

    struct T {
        T()
         : pData (new size_t(1))
         , owner(true)
        { 
            
            std::cout << "malloc" << std::endl; 
        }
        ~T()
        {
            if (owner)
            {
                delete pData;
            }
        }
        T(const T &) = default;
        size_t *pData;          // Memory allocated in the constructor              
        bool   owner;           // pData ownership
        
        template <class T1, class T2>
        friend T operator+(T1 && a, T2 && b){
            
            T c(std::forward<T1>(a), std::forward<T2>(b));
            *c.pData = *a.pData + *b.pData; //UB but works
            return c;
        }
        
        private:
        template <class T1, class T2>
        T(T1 && a, T2 && b) : owner(true)
        {  
            static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, std::decay_t<T1>> && std::is_same_v<T, std::decay_t<T2>>, "only type T is supported");
            if (!std::is_reference<T1>::value)
            {
                pData = a.pData;
                a.owner = false;
                std::cout << "steal data a" << std::endl;   
            }
            else if (!std::is_reference<T2>::value)
            {
                pData = b.pData;
                b.owner = false;
                std::cout << "steal data b" << std::endl;   
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "malloc anyway" << std::endl;
                pData = new size_t(0);
            }            
        }
    };

int main()
{
    T a, b;
    T r = a +b; // malloc
    std::cout << *r.pData << std::endl;
    T r2 = std::move(a) + b; // no malloc
    std::cout << *r2.pData << " a: " << *a.pData << std::endl;
    T r3 = a + std::move(b); // no malloc
    std::cout << *r3.pData << " a: " << *a.pData << " b: " << *b.pData << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An excellent idea. Note that `bool owned` is not required. Just need to set `a.pData = nullptr`. `delete` internally has a `nullptr` check.

Comment: You can also get rid of the UB by moving the type_traits logic from the constructor to the `oprerator+`

Comment: @SreevatsankKadaveru 1. if stealing sets pointer to nullptr - then you will not get the syntax you need. 2 Of course it's possible to implement all the logic in operator + but my assumption was that you probably need operator '-' etc. so i wanted to simplify operator+

Comment: Check out my answer above, I think it solves both the issues and without the UB.